# Keycloak - Authorization Request with Signed Jwt

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm setting up a service with Keycloak as Auth Server, and I want to use "Signed Jwt" as Client Authenticator, so far, I was able to connect the microservice using a keycloak adapter with the information provided by keycloak.json, let me go into more details first:

- Keycloak (12.0.4), self hosted:

  - A "Demo Realm"
  - A client name "springboot-microservice-test"
  - The "Client Authenticator" it's "Signed Jwt"
  - JWKS it's exposed and reachable on the microservice.
  - Some Users with roles that can get access to "springboot-microservice-test", lets call them "user_test" with "user_test_password"

[Keycloak Credentials setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7jkr.png)

- Spring boot Microservice:

  - keycloak-spring-boot-starter, version 12.0.4
  - Settings defined in application properties.
  - Keystore file on resources folder: test_key_store.jks

[Spring boot application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1PIa.png)

On a previous test, with "Client ID and Secret" as Client Authenticator, I had no issues retrieving a token from keycloak and getting access to the microservice, **but I couldn't find any information on how to request the access token on "Signed Jwt"**

[Setup with client_id and client_secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1KKb.png)

Anyone can help me?